# CMake gives undefined reference even if use `link_libraries` command

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

I'm trying to link GLFW using git submodule. Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(guitest VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_executable(guitest main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(glfw)
include_directories(glfw/include)
link_directories(glfw/src)
link_libraries(glfw)
```

I get no errors in CMake, but when I try to build my project I get

```
[build] C:/Users/Konstantin/Documents/sasha/guitest/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
```

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


int main(int, char**){
    GLFWwindow *window;
    if(!glfwInit()){
        std::cout << "Init failure!"<<std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code and GCC 6.3.0 MinGW compiler kit.

Comment: Please create a verbose makefile, and take a look at the commands being executed to see all the flags and options.

Comment: Also note that `include_directories`, `link_directories` and `link_libraries` are all discouraged, in favor of [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories) and [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `link_libraries` affects only on targets which are created **after**. Since your call to `add_executable` precedes `link_libraries`, your executable is not linked.

Correct (but not the best):

```
add_subdirectory(glfw)
link_libraries(glfw)
add_executable(guitest main.cpp)
```

It is preferred to use `target_link_libraries` instead of `link_libraries`.

```
add_subdirectory(glfw)
add_executable(guitest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(guitest PRIVATE glfw)
```

In both cases `include_directories` call could be omitted, since linkage with glfw **target** also ships your executable with GLFW include directories.